# Xcode disable UIButton title fade when tapped

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uibutton

When I tap or hold down on any of my UIButtons, their alpha seems to fade to about 0.1. I never added this functionality in, so I'm assuming it's automatic.

How do I disable this so that my button doesn't fade when tapped or held down? I want my button to remain at alpha 1 all the time.

I've tried `button.adjustsImageWhenHighlighted = NO;` to no avail, as well as a few other suggestions on here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did you try using the same image for both the "normal" and "highlighted" states?

Maybe `showsTouchWhenHighlighted` also affects the situation.

Are you using background images for your buttons too?

Are you disabling the button upon tapping? Disabling also affects appearance (unlike `userInteractionEnabled`).

Are you using IB/Storyboards?

As you can see, there is a number of factors that can play a role into what's happening.

Any code you can show with specifics of your situation?

**Edit:** If you are not using an image (you mentioned `adjustsImageWhenHighlighted`), then just set the button type to "custom" in IB. You won't get the system provided "default" behavior.

Comment: `showsTouch` doesn't help. No image for the button. I'm not disabling the button upon tapping. Yes to IB & Storyboards. I just made a new single view project, placed a button on the screen, ran the app, tapped the button and it automatically fades down its opacity when clicked. I'm looking to remove that fade and keep its opacity at 1.

Comment: Wow, I never realized you could change that setting. This will save me many hours of future frustrations. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

just uptick the Disabled Adjusts Image in your MainStory Board in your buttons configuration next to the Drawing section